# javascript getting setting deleteing cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I am having trouble setting and deleting cookies in php Ive got no problem.. in javascript eh.. lots I know this question is everywhere but all the answers I come across seem to bring me the same fate so I have no idea whats going on.. this is what I have currently.

```
SetCookie("username",ztsUser,14,'/', '');

function SetCookie (name,value,expires,path,domain,secure) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
  }
```

the error:

> expires.toGMTString is not a function

The whole lot of cookie functions I have.. is:

```
    var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

function getCookieVal (offset) {
  var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
  if (endstr == -1) { endstr = document.cookie.length; }
  return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
  }

function GetCookie (name) {
  var arg = name + "=";
  var alen = arg.length;
  var clen = document.cookie.length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < clen) {
    var j = i + alen;
    if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) {
      return getCookieVal (j);
      }
    i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
    if (i == 0) break; 
    }
  return null;
  }

function DeleteCookie (name,path,domain) {
  if (GetCookie(name)) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
    }
  }

function SetCookie (name,value,expires,path,domain,secure) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
  }
```

if anyone knows a better method Im all ears.. but this is what I got at the moment, I need to set, update, delete, get the value of.. cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`toGMTString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString) has been deprecated. Try [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) instead:

```
function SetCookie (name,value,expires,path,domain,secure) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString() : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}
```

You're also passing a number (`14`) when the function expects a Date (`expires.toUTCString`):

```
SetCookie("username", ztsUser, 14, '/', '');
```

What is 14 intended to be? 14 days? Assuming that, you can add this at the top of the function to support both numbers and dates:

```
if ('number' === typeof expires) {
    expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + expires * 86400000);
}
```

`86400000` is the number of milliseconds in a day -- `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`.

Comment: @chris You're mixing types -- passing a number when the function expects a date. See my edit for details.

Answer (score 1):

There are already a number of great libraries for handling cookies in JS.  Why not use one of them? Just go to your favorite search engine and enter "javascript cookie library" to find one.

Comment: (Since I do not have enough reputation to downvote this comment, I'll note that (a) there are contexts where it can be useful to set cookies without spending a lot of time searching for and evaluating libraries, or even just installing them, and (b) this was a question and not an answer. (And, yes, I found this page because I was in one of those contexts - and it turned out my issue was that I was using the default date format (which has worked in major browsers since some time in the last millennium, but which someone decided should be made to no longer work)).)